# Aspectj: why advice cannot be applied? [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Tags: java, aspectj

I have no idea why advice cannot be applied.

The aspect code seems to be correct. However, the warning message suggests that the advice defined in the LoggingAspect class is not being applied to the submitSms method.

Aspect implementation

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect{

    @Around("@annotation(utils.log.LogExecutionTime) && execution(* *(..)) ")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return logExecutionTime(joinPoint, null);
    }

    
    @Around("@annotation(utils.log.LogExecutionTimeWithFirstParameter) && execution(* *(..)) ")
    public Object logExecutionTimeWithFirstParameter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        final var args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        if (args.length > 0)
            return logExecutionTime(joinPoint, args[0].toString());
        else
            return logExecutionTime(joinPoint, null);
    }

    private Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String args) throws Throwable {
        final var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final var logPrefix = createLogPrefix(joinPoint, args);
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            logExecution(start, logPrefix);
        }
    }

    private void logExecution(final long start, final String logPrefix) {
        final var executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        log.info("S13423;{} executed in {} ms", logPrefix, executionTime);
    }
```

Calling class in another package:

```
@LogExecutionTime
    public void submitSms(List<SubmitSm> submitMessages) {
        CloudhopperSmppConnection smppConnection = fetchConnectionRoundRobin();
        for (SubmitSm sm : submitMessages) {
            try {
                log.debug("2644;smpp message submit to {}", sm.getDestAddress());
                String messageId = smppConnection.submit(sm);
                if (messageId == null || StringUtil.isEmpty(messageId)) {
                    throw new SmppSubmitException("failed to receive smSubmit response within given time");
                }
                log.info("2645;smpp message submitted to {} successful: {}", sm.getDestAddress(), messageId);
            } catch (SmppConnectionException e) {
                log.warn("2646;smpp message submission to {} failed due to {}", sm.getDestAddress(), e.getMessage());
                throw new SmppSubmitException("could not send smpp over connection", e);
            }
        }
```

LoggingAspect.class [warning] advice defined in utils.log.LoggingAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for the interesting question, but please note, that there is insufficient information to answer it, because the devil is in the details about programming. AOP is no exception. Please publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so I can reproduce the problem. It could be anywhere from package names to weaving method (load-time, compile time) to configuration. I am unbwilling to speculate, so please give me something to analyse.